# Margin of error for non-dichotomous data

Tags: confidence-interval, binomial-distribution, survey, standard-error, multinomial-distribution

I am trying to calculate the margin of error for specific survey questions. I know how to calculate this if the data are dichotomous (i.e., a 75-25 or 60-40 split). But how do you deal with questions that have more than one response? For example:

> Which of the following age ranges best describes you?
>   () Younger than 18
>   () 18 to 30
>   () 30 to 50
>   () 50 to 70
>   () Over 70

- Is the margin of error calculated for this question by treating each response as it were a separate question? (That is, if 20 respondents out of 200 picked "Over 70", would I treat "Over 70" as a separate question that has a 90-10 split?)
- If not, how would margin or error be calculated?